# preg_match html table match

Tags: php, html, preg-match

Here's my PHP Code, I am currently having:

```
function getStatus($file, $dob){
    $url = "http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/statusTracker/trackStatusForFileNoNew?fileNo=$file&applDob=$dob";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);

    echo preg_match('/^<table cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"4\" align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" role=\"presentation\">(.*)<\/table>/',$data, $converted);

    //$converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
    //return round($converted, 3); 
}
```

I would like to fetch all content between `<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" align="center" width="100%" role="presentation">` and `</table>`

Currently `preg_match` returns `0`.

Your support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any table with such attribute values `cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4"` on the site you have specified. There are tables with only `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` attributes

Comment: There may be several problems with your regex. First of all, if you need such specific help I suggest you to include text should be parsed to the question. As for the regex, you don't need to escape double quotes, you may want to remove new line meta char `^` and substitute every space with a `\s+`. Please, notice that any little alteration to the page will result in a failing match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Your regular expression (preg_match) starts with a caret icon: `^`

This means it should look for your expression at the beginning of the string. Just remove the caret:

```
preg_match('/<table cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"4\" align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" role=\"presentation\">(.*)<\/table>/',$data, $converted);
```

Now it should look everywhere in the HTML file.

**Some food for thought**

For debugging it would be wise to make sure that the content of the $data variable is what you are looking for. Since you are referring to an external URL you never know which exact HTML structure/file content you get back. Also the response might change without you being aware of it (for example: maybe 1 week ago the `cellspacing=\"4\"` was present but now is not any longer. If you really have to do it that way write code that expects the response is not what you want and throws an adequate error.

When I look at the HTML file you are reading I do not see the search term anywhere so I would assume even with the corrected regex you will still get 0 as result.

**To make your life easier**

A nice tool to check if your regex is working or not is this one: http://regexr.com/

I used it a lot until I finally understood regular expressions (and still do).

Comment: In my opinion http://www.phpliveregex.com is better as it works on mobile phones too.